# Single function for state change no multiple states whit similar name

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function

I'm trying to create a function for the state change, on multiple states ...

I have the following states in the `constructor()`

```
this.state={
  answer1:"",
  answer2:"",
  answer3:"",
  answer4:"",
  answer5:"", 
  //answerN... (25 to be exact)
}
```

I have this Question component which is a `<p>` tag and 6 radio buttons for the question  answers

I make 5 instances of this component

```
<Question addAnswer={this.addAnswer} title="...." />
<Question addAnswer={this.addAnswer} title="..." /> 
....
```

each  calling the same function named `addAnswer()`

```
addAnswer = (answerValue) => {
  this.setState({answer1:answerValue},()=>console.log(this.state.answer1))
}
```

this function  will change only the `answer1 state`

So  how to make it something like this to work

```
addAnswer = (answerNumber,answerValue) => {
    this.setState({ answer + answerNumber: answerValue },()=>console.log(this.state.answer + answerNumber))
}
```

Is function like this possible?

Is there an option of making the answer state an Array and how will I determine which index of this array is answered and on later changed ???

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to pass the whole name of the attribute as a parameter to the function, instead of just a number. I think it looks more readable and easy to understand.

Like this:

```
addAnswer = (answerCode, answerValue) => {
    this.setState({ [answerCode]: answerValue }, () => 
        console.log(this.state[answerCode])
    )
}
```

If I were you I would probably change the structure to look something like this:

```
{ 
    "answers": {
        1: {
            "code": 1,
            "value": "Yes"
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you are passing the value to the reducer, you can pass the whole answer object:

```
{
    "code": 2,
    "value": "No"
}
```

And to add a new answer:

```
addAnswer = (answer) => {
    this.setState({ [answer.code]: answer })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to iterate over some data array, which holds e.g. *titles*:

```
someArray.map((title, i) => (
   <Question addAnswer={() => this.addAnswer(answerValue, i)} title={title} />
);
```

Then you will be able to reference to an item on specified index `i`.

```
addAnswer = (answerValue, i) => {
  this.setState({ `answer${i}`: answerValue });
};
```

**Note**: You didn't specify from where `answerValue` prop comes from + `i` starts at `0`.

Comment: `answer${i}` gives me an unexpected token error ...  any ideas?

Comment: @ГеоргиДимитранов Maybe your ver doesn't support es6. Try simply `"answer" + i`.